# Route subdomain keeping the user logged in for subdomains

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I have a sub-domain, let's say for example:

```
Route::domain('test.localhost')
    ->group(function () {

    Route::resource('test', 'Wallet\WalletController');

});
```

If my user is logged in a http://localhost but visits the test.localhost, it redirects them to the login page. Is it possible to keep the user logged in for sub-domains too?

Comment: If my answer works for you, please accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are bound to domains. Under config/session.php you must have `'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),`.

Then put `SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost` in your .env file and it should work for all subdomains and the main domain.

Sessions can be restricted on the path also.

[image]

Comment: how to do this in node js? any idea?

Comment: I'm not into node js, but I would say there is no copy&paste answer. It depends on the framework/lib you are using for setting the cookie. But the goal is the same: append the domain with a dot